# Which file should be included in using statement for cascading DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-select

Which file should be included in using statement for cascading DropDownList for MVC2?

I am getting some compilation error due to reference problems.
I am referring this article.

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx

Comment: When you write "I am getting some error", the *very next thing you should do* is to tell us the specific error you're getting. We can't see your screen from here, can't read your mind, and you've posted absolutely no code or other information. If you want help, ask specific questions and provide the information we need to help you solve the problem. As far as the link you've provided, the code there displays all of the references used properly; if you're getting errors, you've not done something properly.

Comment: @kenwhite - Actually I meant, what's the base class for cascading dropdownlist ? Thanks for corrections.